# How To Replace Values With Text In Cgridview

Tags: php, yii

In admin.php, I have a gridview where I created a dropdownlist. I have the following values, i.e 0-> No Activity
            1->Pending 
            2->Approved 
            3-> Rejected. 
          How can I specify here in the below code and display the corresponding values for the numbers in the gridview cells.

```
array(
                'name' => 'Test',
            'value' =>?
                    'visible' => ($approval=="1")?true:false,
                'filter' => array('0' => 'No Activity', '1' => 'Pending','2' => 'Approved', '3' => 'Rejected',''=>'All'),                    
//                    'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;font-size: 15px !important;'),
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 500px;'),
            ),
```

Comment: @Ninad I need to replace the values of 1,2,3 with corresponding text in their cells.

Comment: @Ninad they are static. I have given $data->test. But I don't know how to mention for multiple values if $data->test=0/1/2/3

Comment: @Ninad Say suppose you have a field with 0 and 1 as values. What will you do. You can use a ternary operator to tell the value has to be replaced with true for approved and false for reject.

Comment: @Ninad I know for two values but not for multiple values

Comment: @Ninad 'value' =>'$data->test? "Approved": "Rejected"',

Comment: Then what is you want is compare four values ??

Comment: @Ninad  Yes exactly...How can I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare array with the dropdownlist values on the controller:

```
$list = array('0' => 'No Activity', '1' => 'Pending','2' => 'Approved', '3' => 'Rejected', ''=>'All');
```

And send this to the view.

And in the CgridView use this array $list like this:

```
    array(            // display 'author.username' using an expression
            'name'=>'Test',
            'value'=>function ($data, $row) use ($list){ return $data->field? $list[$data->field] : 'All'; },
            'visible' => ($approval=="1")? true : false,
//                    'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;font-size: 15px !important;'),
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 500px;'),
        ),
```

Where $data->field it's the row field name.

Comment: Perfect! ^^ Thanks to you ;)